# Azure functions stopped working after Core 3.0 update

Tags: azure-functions, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0, azure-function-app

The code is working in Core 3.0 preview7 version, but after updating to 3.0 Azure functions started giving an error.

The error comes if I try to access builder service object. Also not able to debug the issue. Also tried updating Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.0 but still the same error.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
    var descriptor = builder.Services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IConfiguration)); // error after adding this
        var currentDirectory = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")}\\site\\wwwroot";


        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        var configuration = configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();
}
}
```

When executing the below error comes: 
Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IFunctionsHostBuilder.get_Services()'.

Comment: The word `preview` indicates its not stable, so why ?

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET Core 3.0 not currently available for Azure App Service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#aspnet-core-30-not-currently-available-for-azure-app-service) [Microsoft Docs]

I understand the [preview versions of .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service) [Microsoft Docs] are available on the Azure service.

Azure Functions 3.0, which will be fully compatible with Core 3.0, will be available in October - see [this announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/200)

Comment: The links refer to deployment in App Service, Is there any solution to make working in the local environment for debugging.

Comment: I cannot find anything on a solution for the local envirnonment.  Azure Functions 3.0 with full compability with Core 3.0 will be available in October - see [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/200)