# Deploying .NET Core 3.0 API to Azure Web App using Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, .net-core-3.0

I'm attempting to upgrade my API from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.0, but I cannot get the Azure Web App to actually run the application using 3.0.

My build pipeline configuration:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core 3'
  inputs:
    version: 3.x
- script: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: efcore-migration-script-generator-task@0
  inputs:
    projectpath: 'Models/Models.csproj'
    databasecontexts: 'DataContext'
    startupprojectpath: 'Api/Api.csproj'
    targetfolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/migrations'
- script: dotnet publish --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  displayName: 'dotnet publish $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I then have a multi-stage release pipeline that publishes the artifact to Azure using the `Azure App Service Deploy` Task. Everything runs without issue

I've installed the preview extension, as directed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#install-the-preview-site-extension), and running the powershell command `Test-Path D:\home\SiteExtensions\AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86\` returns `true`. I'm still seeing the following error though.

[ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jUme.png)

Back in Powershell, running `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --list-runtimes` shows that it only recognizes .NET Core 2 runtimes, despite the 3.0 runtime being present. As best I can tell, installing the site extension doesn't update the path to use the new `dotnet` version, and the Azure Devops deploy task doesn't seem to have any options to override the default. Has anyone managed to get a .NET Core 3 app deployed through Azure Devops Release Pipelines?

Comment: I doubt if azure App service supports .Net Core 3.0 yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133089/azure-functions-stopped-working-after-core-3-0-update

Comment: @Venky they claim to support it if using the Site Extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#install-the-preview-site-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't consider it a good solution by any means, but the workaround I'm using right now that is working is to add a `web.config` file that passes the full path to the site extension version of `dotnet`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="D:\home\SiteExtensions\AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86\dotnet" arguments=".\Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I'm still looking for a solution that isn't so error prone.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT But it is a hack of a solution and MS claims to support 3.0 working.