# Azure Functions on .net core 3.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Now that .Net Core 3.0 has released what's the story for Azure Functions on core3?

When I try to flip a project to
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>` it still reports as running on 2.2.

If I try to access an api that's 3.0 only it explodes, which makes sense since it seems to be forcing it's runtime despite the project settings.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133089/azure-functions-stopped-working-after-core-3-0-update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Functions is not available for .NET CORE 3 yet. For more information check [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/200)

### Update

The Azure Functions 3.0 preview is now available!

Please see this post for instructions on how to use the preview on Azure and how to use the 3.0 tools locally:
https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm

### Update 2

The Azure Functions 3.0 are generally available since December 9, 2019.

For migration instructions refer to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions

Comment: The issue was updated : .NET Core 3 is available in preview, and should be available in 2020

Comment: I looked at that post for instructions to preview, but after updating templates according to the instructions, the "Azure Functions v3 Preview" isn't available in the dropdown. I was going to leave a comment on the blog asking about it, but the amount of information they ask before you can comment are too much.

Comment: @PaulDempsey did you set the environment variable (AzureFunctionsHiddenTagsVisible)? And restart VS? It worked for me..

Comment: same issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday (09.12.2019), Microsoft [announced the Azure Functions 3.0 go-live release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-go-live-release-for-azure-functions-v3/) which supports .NET Core 3.1 which has a Long Term Support (LTS).

On March 3, 2020, the Support for .NET Core 3.0 ends - so for anyone reading this, you should use **.NET Core 3.1 and Azure Functions 3.0**

Further reading: [How and why you should upgrade your .NET Azure Functions to 3.0](https://about-azure.com/2019/12/11/how-and-why-you-should-upgrade-your-net-azure-functions-to-3-0/)